# pass an argument with escape characters to a script with docker exec

Tags: bash, docker, shell, escaping

I would like to pass the variable `$styled` to a script inside a docker container.

The docker command would look something like

```
docker exec container_name "/bin/bash -c cd /where/the/script/is && ./echo.sh $styled"
```

the `echo.sh` would look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e $1
```

the variable `$styled` contains escape characters, so lets say it is:

```
styled=$'\e[7mSOME_TEXT\e[27m'
```

---

On my local computer i can pass the variable to a local echo.sh without any issues, unfortunately it doesn't work while using dockers exec.

the error message is something like:

```
./echo.sh \x1b[7mFF1SOME_TEXT\x1b[27m: no such file or directory": unknown
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with how escaping works, single quotes, double quotes and so on, but I am simply confused by all those layers.

---

I also tried:

```
docker exec container_name "/bin/bash -c 'cd /where/the/script/is && ./echo.sh '$P'"
```

which results in

```
stat /bin/bash -c 'cd /where/the/script/is && ./echo.sh '\x1b[7mSOME_TEXT\x1b[27m': no such file or directory"
```

Comment: Try `docker exec container_name /bin/bash -c 'cd /where/the/script/is && ./echo.sh "$1"' _ "$styled"`? What is the entrypoing of the container?

Comment: @KamilCuk this way the "echo.sh"script is executed, but $1 seems to be empty. what kind of function is this? i never saw the underscore

Comment: The arguments to `bash -c` are the script itself, followed by `$0`, `$1`, `$2`... etc. The underscore simply provides a dummy value for `$0` so that the following argument(s) will be numbered like you expect.

Comment: Well, `docker run -ti --rm alpine /bin/sh -c 'cd /tmp/ && echo "$1"' _ "blabla"` works. What is the containers entrypoint? Did you followed same qoutation? You could also `docker exec -w /where/the/script/is` and pass variable with `--env`

Comment: it worked! the empty variable was my fault :) thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `bash -c` needs to be quoted.

```sh
docker exec container_name /bin/bash -c "cd /where/the/script/is && ./echo.sh '$styled'"
```

The code you exhibit doesn't do anything useful with the `cd`; if your real code cares which directory it's invoked from, maybe refactor it so it doesn't. Then this is suddenly much simpler.

```sh
docker exec container_name /where/the/script/is/echo.sh "$styled"
```

Still you need to fix the quoting in `echo.sh`, too:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$1"
```

or perhaps better yet

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$@"
```

Maybe you still need `docker -it` to get output back.

The single quotes in the first snippet above are brittle, and will fail if `$styled` contains an unescaped literal single quote. If you genuinely need to pass in complex quoted strings to `bash -c`, maybe do someting like

```sh
docker exec container_name /bin/bash -c 'cd /where/the/script/is && ./echo.sh "$1"' -- "$styled"
```

Passing in literal terminal escape codes is dubious, but I guess trying to fix that antipattern is a lost cause. Maybe at least I could convince you to use `printf` instead of `echo -e`?

Comment: since this is the first and also most complete answer, I will accept this one even if @kamilcuk was a bit faster. thank you so much!